# Modifying value in abstracted struct

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have this current situation while working with structs and protocols and was curious to know how can I access and modify value in this case:

```
import Foundation

struct Garage {
    var vehicles : [VehicleProtocol]
}

protocol VehicleProtocol {
    var id: String { get }
}

protocol TwoWheelsProtocol: VehicleProtocol {
    var id: String { get }
    var uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut: String { get set     }
}

struct TwoWheels: TwoWheelsProtocol {
    var id: String
    var uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut: String
}

protocol FourWheelsProtocol: VehicleProtocol {
    var uniqueFourWheelsAttribut: String { get set }
}

struct FourWheels: FourWheelsProtocol {
    var id: String
    var uniqueFourWheelsAttribut: String
}

func printVehicules(of garage: Garage) {
    for vehicle in garage.vehicles {
        if vehicle is TwoWheelsProtocol {
            let tw = vehicle as! TwoWheelsProtocol
            print("\(tw.id) | \(tw.uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut)")
        }

        if vehicle is FourWheelsProtocol {
            let tw = vehicle as! FourWheelsProtocol
            print("\(tw.id) | \(tw.uniqueFourWheelsAttribut)")
        }
    }
}

let vehicle0 = TwoWheels(id: "0", uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut: "vehicle0")
let vehicle1 = FourWheels(id: "1", uniqueFourWheelsAttribut: "vehicle1")

var a = Garage(vehicles: [vehicle0, vehicle1])

printVehicules(of: a)
```

The `printVehicules(of: a)` result is:

```
0 | vehicle0
1 | vehicle1
```

How can I modify vehicle0 `uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut` to have:

```
0 | modified
1 | vehicle1
```

I can use

```
if a is TwoWheelsProtocol {
    let tw as! TwoWheelsProtocol
    ......
}
```

but since the cast result is in another variable, the modification doesn't affect the origin value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) says

> Classes have additional capabilities that structures don’t have:
>   - Reference counting allows more than one reference to a class instance.

So `let tw as! TwoWheelsProtocol` always creates a new object since `TwoWheels` is a struct. To avoid this you can turn `TwoWheels` into a class:

```
class TwoWheels: TwoWheelsProtocol {
    var id: String
    var uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut: String

    init(id: String, uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut = uniqueTwoWheelsAttribut
    }
}
```

Now `let tw as! TwoWheelsProtocol` does not create a new copy, but rather only a new reference to the object.

#### What you can improve

Require `VehicleProtocol` to only allow classes to implement the protocol. This way you can be sure a cast and a change made does actually change the referenced object instead of just a copy of it.

```
protocol VehicleProtocol: class {
    var id: String { get }
}
```

You can use a more compact casting method.

```
if var tw = vehicle as? TwoWheelsProtocol {
    // Modify tw.
}

guard var tw = vehicle as? TwoWheelsProtocol else {
    return
}
// Modify tw.
```

Comment: ty for the great explanation and the improve tip.

Comment: shouldn't be if var instead of if let ?

Comment: @Florian_L I don’t usually modify so my bad. Yes!